# Cloning element with jquery noconflict enabled

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clone an element (#flip-data) change its ID (to #flip-data-clone) and then append it to the DIV (#flip_data_container). However can't get it to work.

The code:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
   .....
   $j("#flip-data").clone().attr("id","#flip-data-clone").appendTo( "#flip_data_container" );
   .....
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only put `#` at the beginning of an ID when it's being used as a selector, not when you want to assign it as the ID to an element.

```
$j("#flip-data").clone().attr("id","flip-data-clone").appendTo( "#flip_data_container" );
```

I have no idea why you think this is related to use of `jQuery.noConflict()`, as I'm sure the code would have failed the same way without it.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that still isn't working (it isn't being appended, not showing as a child of #flip_data_container). Good pick up on the # which is unnecessary, don't know why I didn't see that earlier :s  I don't think the problem is the noconflict it was more for explaining why I am using $j rather than just $.

Comment: tested and fine in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/r1Lwh4kq/), code should be working, but still isn't...so something else must be screwy.

Comment: frigging h....the problem was using _ instead of - in the IDs...gggrrrrr.
thanks much @Barmar. At least you fixed another problem that I completely missed (the 1 too many #).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

1. Add a class to element `#flip-data`, ex: `.flip-data`
2. Clone `.flip-data` class and append it to `#flip_data_container`
3. Add id to new `.flip-data` in `#flip_data_container`

```js
$(function(){
    $(".flip-data").clone().appendTo("#flip_data_container" );
    $("#flip_data_container .flip-data").attr("id","flip-data-clone");
})
```